# Eror 401 Unauthorized en https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{{idGrupo}}/reports - oauth2 client_credentials

Tags: nodejs, postman, azure, powerbi

el api [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{{idGrupo}}/reports](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/%7B%7BidGrupo%7D%7D/reports) me retorna 401

estoy utlizando [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant}}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7Btenant%7D%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)
para obtener mi accesToken
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la informacion de mi accesToken
[image]

no veo la informacion "scp": "App.Read.All Capacity.Read.All ..."
en el access token.

me faltara alguna configuracion ??